# HDFS Offline Image Viewer takes hours

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I execute these commands, it is very slow and always takes five hours or more to finish.

```sh
hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage ${t_save_fsimage_path}

# 获取下载的fsimage具体文件路径               
t_fsimage_file=`ls ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage*`

# 处理fsimage为可读的csv格式文件             
hdfs oiv -i ${t_fsimage_file} -o ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage.csv -p Delimited

# 删除fsimage.csv的首行数据          
sed -i -e "1d" ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage.csv

# 创建数据目录      
hadoop fs -test -e ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage || hdfs dfs -mkdir -p ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage

# 拷贝fsimage.csv到指定的路径          
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage.csv ${t_save_fsimage_path}/fsimage/
```

[image]

Comment: And your question is how to make it go faster? Add more CPU/RAM to your server

Comment: Yes, i just want it a few minutes to finish ! Now my linux is CPU 20 vcores and mem 64G, i think it's not the solution of the problem.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to get the fsimage, and back it up to HDFS in CSV format? The editlog of the namenode should already be preserving the state of your cluster. If you want a backup, setup high availability mode

Comment: Anyway thanks. I do this ,just want to analysize the contents, filesize... of hdfs meta data. So i must need fsimage . Do you know well the hadoop source code , i want to know these commands how to do work?

Comment: Hadoop source code is on github

Comment: Thank you very much. I change it on the other way , now i 'm handling it. But i still understand why "hdfs oiv -p Delimited"  in this way to process fsimage so slowly!

Comment: It is not MapReduce, and it's single threaded. And needs to parse and convert a potentially large file?

Comment: Something you are right, It's really not a MR job . And my fsimage size is 1G , when it complete  the final output is 2G. So it will read 1G fsimage and write 2G output , but i can't confirm it's single threaded or not . Because i don't discover it in hadoop source code. In addition， if i run "hdfs oiv -p XML" ,it's very quickly and the output is 5G.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/offlineImageViewer/OfflineImageViewerPB.java

Comment: You think it's a single threaded?

Comment: Almost certainly. I see no reason for it to use more than one thread. It needs to read one file and write another. Threads don't operate well under those conditions

Comment: But , you can explain why i run "hdfs oiv -p XML" this command , it's very quick(few minutes) and the output is 5G.

Comment: Probably because XML can be written in a hierarchical manner that CSV cannot

Comment: Hi，i know the reson that because my hadoop is 2.6.0 but hadoop2.6.0 don't provide the way "hdfs oiv -p Delimited", but the default way is transfer XML so it's fast.

Answer (score 0):

The below helped especially when dealing with a large `fsimage`:

1. Setting the java heap size:
   `export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx55G"`
2. Using the -t or --temp option to use temporary dir (instead of memory) to cache intermediate result: e.g., `hdfs oiv -i fsimage_example -o fsimage_example.csv -p Delimited -delimiter "|" --temp /tmp/fsimage_example`

Answer (score 0):

You could either programmatically analyze the fsimage using [HFSA lib](https://github.com/marcelmay/hfsa) or [HFSA cli tool](https://github.com/marcelmay/hfsa/tree/master/tool) (depending on your use case).